# Download a file without wget or curl

Tags: shell, ftp, http, file-download

How would one go about downloading a file from the command line without using
Wget or Curl?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using FTP:

```
ftp -A -v mirrors.sonic.net <<eof
binary
get cygwin/x86_64/setup.xz setup.xz
eof
```

Using OpenSSL - note this only works for HTTPS:

```
openssl s_client -quiet -connect superuser.com:443 <<eof
GET / HTTP/1.0
Host: superuser.com

eof
```

Using lynx:

```
lynx -source example.com > index.html
```

Answer (score 2):

This works with `telnet` instead of `lynx`:

```
(echo 'GET /'; echo; sleep 1; ) | telnet example.com 80
```