# How to download file from docker container image without curl / wget?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, docker, alpine-linux, posix

I'm in the process of writing [container features](https://containers.dev/implementors/create-feature/) and I want to be able to install package on `debian:latest`, `ubuntu:latest` and `alpine:latest`. To do so, I'm willing to leverage [pacapt](https://github.com/icy/pacapt), a pure shell cross-os solution.

First, I need to be able to [download the script itself](https://github.com/icy/pacapt#installation) and that's where is become tricky. The base images have little to offer (no `curl`, `wget` or `telnet`), see available package on bare images:

- [`debian:latest` (bullseye) rootfs](https://github.com/debuerreotype/docker-debian-artifacts/blob/72073f82c7/bullseye/rootfs.manifest)
- [`ubuntu:latest` (jammy) rootfs](https://git.launchpad.net/cloud-images/+oci/ubuntu-base/tree/ubuntu-jammy-oci-amd64-root.manifest?h=refs/tags/dist-jammy-amd64-20221101&id=94ab0c78ee1594e0ef5daa7a191edc55d69385db)
- [`alpine:latest` rootfs](https://github.com/alpinelinux/docker-alpine/blob/a791ed3b04/x86_64/alpine-minirootfs-3.17.0-x86_64.tar.gz) (a `tar.gz`)

### Constraints

#### Shell

I'm looking for a POSIX solution.

#### Available command

Here is what is missing (prefixed by `-`) and what is present (prefixed by `+`) on all of them.

```
-curl
-wget
-openssl
-telnet
-git
-nc
-netcat
+awk
```

#### HTTPS

The file I aim to download is `pacapt` script hosted on GitHub, located at

> https://raw.githubusercontent.com/icy/pacapt/ng/pacapt

### Questions

How to download file from docker container image without curl / wget?

Related:

- [Download a file without wget or curl](https://superuser.com/a/447875/174465)

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a multi-stage build and download the file into a throwaway image first, then copy it into the target image. An example is shown in the documentation for [multi-stage builds](https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-stage/). All of this should be put in a single Dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:1.16 AS builder
WORKDIR /go/src/github.com/alexellis/href-counter/
RUN go get -d -v golang.org/x/net/html  
COPY app.go ./
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 go build -a -installsuffix cgo -o app .

FROM alpine:latest  
RUN apk --no-cache add ca-certificates
WORKDIR /root/
COPY --from=builder /go/src/github.com/alexellis/href-counter/app ./
CMD ["./app"]
```

The general syntax is:

```
COPY --from=stage_or_image source_path_in_the_image target_path
```

It works like regular `COPY`, except the source is the image specified, rather than the build directory on the host. You can specify independent images too:

```
COPY --from=nginx:latest /etc/nginx/nginx.conf /nginx.conf
```

For your use case you would either find an image with the file you need and copy from it, or alternatively first use a container with curl/wget to download the file, then copy it.

Comment: I'm not in control of how people are going to use the [feature](https://containers.dev/implementors/features/), that's why I look for a solution that is as standalone as possible